# how to find max( expression)?

Tags: exponentiation, maxima-minima

how to find max. for
$$\max(x^{2},x^{2a}),$$ 
where  $x \geq 0$ and $0<a\leq 1$ (or $a \geq 1$).

i don't know if this correct 
in case $0<a\leq 1$ 
$$\max(x^{2},x^{2a})=x^{2}$$ 
and in case $a \geq 1$
$$\max(x^{2},x^{2a})=x^{2a}$$

Comment: Please remember that you can choose an aswer among the given if the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

Consider a part the trivial cases $x=0$ and $x=1$ and then the two cases

- $0< x < 1\implies x^2>x^n \qquad$ for $n>2$
- $x>1\implies x^2<x^n\qquad$ for $n>2$

Comment: Thanks so much, is it right $$ x^{2} \geq (x^{a})^{2}$$ if **a** fraction between 0 and 1, $$ x^{2} \leq (x^{a})^{2}$$ if **a** fraction between 1 and 2 ?

Comment: As indicated in the given hint, you need at first to define what is the interval for x. Indeed for $0<x<1$ for example $x^2>x^3$ but for $x>1 \implies x^2<x^3$